# Accent insensitive search in Grails

Tags: grails, diacritics, compass-lucene, grails-searchable

How to make full text search using [Grails Searchable Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) accent insensitive ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this problem with help of [Peter Ledbrook's post](http://grails-plugins.847840.n3.nabble.com/Accent-insensitive-searches-td3012945.html), however some effort was needed:

Since latest searchable plugin uses Lucene 2.4.1 which does not contain [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.9.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java#ASCIIFoldingFilter) (available since 2.9.0) and [ISOLatin1AccentFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.4.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ISOLatin1AccentFilter.java#ISOLatin1AccentFilter) doesn't support many languages I have created custom filter for [stripping accents](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/10/how-to-strip-accents-from-strings-using-java-6/):

```
    import java.text.Normalizer
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream

    class StripAccentsFilter extends TokenFilter {

        StripAccentsFilter(TokenStream input)   {
            super(input)
        }

        public final Token next(Token reusableToken) {

            assert reusableToken

            Token nextToken = input.next(reusableToken)
            if (nextToken) {
                nextToken.setTermBuffer(Normalizer.normalize(nextToken.termBuffer() as String, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""))
                return nextToken
            }
            return null
        }
    }
```

and corresponding filter provider:

```
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream
    import org.compass.core.config.CompassSettings
    import org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerTokenFilterProvider

    class StripAccentsFilterProvider implements LuceneAnalyzerTokenFilterProvider {

        public void configure(CompassSettings paramCompassSettings) {
        }

        public TokenStream createTokenFilter(TokenStream paramTokenStream) {
            return new StripAccentsFilter(paramTokenStream)
        }

    }
```

Now all you need to do is to register this filter provider in configuration of searchable plugin (grails-app/conf/Searchable.groovy):

```
compassSettings = [
    'compass.engine.analyzer.default.filters': 'stripAccents',
    'compass.engine.analyzer.search.filters': 'stripAccents',
    'compass.engine.analyzerfilter.stripAccents.type': 'StripAccentsFilterProvider' 
]
```